# does django send_mail() support custom 'from'?

Tags: django, sendmail, sendgrid, email

my django app is sending emails (via SendGrid API) using `django.core.mail`'s `send_mail`

```
send_mail(
    subject='foo',
    message=message,
    from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
    recipient_list=[user.email],
    fail_silently=False,
    html_message=rendered)
```

the emails send fine but since it's sending from hi@myapp.com the email "From" alias in inboxes just shows up as "hi", and I'd like to make it more verbose so my recipients know who sent them the email ("Hi from AppName"). I don't see any field in send_mail docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/) for customizing how the "From" sender alias string appears (beyond the email itself) other than 'The “From:” header of the email will be the value of the SERVER_EMAIL setting'. does django's `send_mail` not support this (i.e., I need to rewrite this to using a sendgrid lib? https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python?) or is there a config setting in SendGrid where I can automatically set 'fromname'? thanks

Is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example includes `from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`. [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) say that the more verbose form is permitted, for example:

```
from_email="Hi from Appname <hi@myapp.com>",
```

You might also be able to change [`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL) to the more verbose form. However the docs don't say whether this is supported or not, so I'm not sure whether this would cause problems somewhere.